# Unable to create epic using postman

Tags: api, postman, jira, jira-rest-api

URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue

```
body:
{
"fields":
{
    "project":
    {
        "key": "DEMO"

    },
    "Epic Name": "Epic Name 01",
    "summary": "REST EXAMPLE1",
    "description":"Creating an Epic via REST",
    "issuetype": 
    {
        "name": "Epic"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What else have you tried? We're there any error messages? Are you sure `Epic Name` is the correct property name? Is this running locally, do you have any logging? Have you tried it in anything other than Postman? What Headers are you sending? What does the JIRA API Documentation say is the correct structure of the message? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-create-a-Epic-and-a-Story-using-JIRA-REST-Json/qaq-p/476229

Answer (score 0):

Jira will return `415 Unsupported Media Type` if Content-type wasn't specified.

Add to your header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I tried this and it worked:

```
{
   "fields": {

      "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
      "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
      "customfield_10104": "Epic Name 01",
      "issuetype": {
          "name": "Epic"
      },
      "project":
      {
          "key": "JIRA"
      }
   }
}
```

If you'd like to create an issue with "Epic Name" you should refernce it using it's customfield ID.

To get "Epic Name" customfield id: use the following rest:

```
http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/customFields?search=Name%20of%20Epic
```